# Associative array in UML class diagram

Tags: arrays, uml, associative

I have an array that I want to show in a class diagram.

```
protected static $config = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname' => ''
    );
```

is this a correct way :

## $config( key: 'localhost', value: '', key: 'username', value: '', key: 'password', value: '', key: 'dbname', value: '')

and underlined the whole line for static

Answer (score 0):

Usually one doesn't use UML to configure things, but you can do it. You would need to create instance specifications to get the result you want.

You could create an instance specification, `associativeArrayInstanceSpec1` of type `AssociativeArray` that composes a bunch of other `AssociativeArrayEntry` instance specifications that each have a specific key and value. Then you could declare a property with a default value in `SomeClass` as `config : AssociativeArray [1] = associativeArrayInstanceSpec1`.

Comment: Still can't understand how can I show all the key-value pairs ?