# How to model associative arrays in UML?

Tags: uml, associative-array

I know there are some related questions about this question, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558319/associative-array-in-uml-class-diagram), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812190/modelling-types-with-uml-based-on-associative-arrays) and [this](http://wiki.c2.com/?AssociativeArrayInUml), but no one of them really helped me. My array keys are dynamic, so I can't create an additional class holding this attributes (like done in second linked question).

The idea of my concept is to hold instances of classes as follows:

```
$instances = [
    "nameOfClass" => [
        //instances of "nameOfClass"
    ],
    "nameOfClass2" => [
        //instances of "nameOfClass2"
    ]
    //some more classes
];
```

But I don't know how to model these concept with UML when the array-key is unanimously with the class-name.

Is there a way to model my concept/in general associative arrays?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You are losing useful abstractions by focusing on implementation details. Why stop at associative arrays? Why not model the machine code while you're at it?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to express this in UML is to use a qualifier, or qualified association. There you have an owner and that has a qualifier, i.e., "key", that associates to a class. Further you can give the qualifier a type, to express that your key is a String, int, or Object of a certain class.

[image]

See also p. 206 of UML 2.5.

Comment: This doesn't seem to match what he asked. The OP seems to want to maintain every instance of every "class" in one place.

Comment: Yes, and that exactlyis what associative arrays do, because UML ingores the implementation details; and that is what it is design for. Therefore this is not only correct, it is also very commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to simulate classes in PHP by building an associative array of named classes, where each class name (e.g., `Person` or `ShoppingCart`) maps to a collection of instances. If so, you are essentially trying to represent a non-OO simulation of OO in UML. UML is already OO, so you are trying to jump through your own belly button!

Unlike in PHP, in UML, a Property (i.e., a variable) must be owned by a Classifier, which is usually a Class or an Association. Therefore, to express `$instances` as a Property, it would have to be owned by a Class or Association.

If you are willing to accept that there will be an owning Class (let's call it `ClassIndex`), you will then need another UML Class, probably called `Class`, to represent each class (e.g., `Person` or `ShoppingCart`) and its attributes (e.g., `firstName` and `lastName`). Are you getting confused by the meta-programming yet? We haven't even gotten to the part about how to track the attributes of each class and so on.

While UML has all of the parts you need to re-invent OO programming, you have a fundamental mismatch between UML and PHP. The same would be true for C or assembler. UML allows you to work at a much higher level of abstraction than those languages. Therefore, I recommend you get an OO simulation working, then use UML to model your domain classes (e.g., `Person` or `ShoppingCart`) and generate a "configuration" that your OO simulation can run.