# How to describe a map of standard types in UML?

Tags: dictionary, templates, uml

I've seen a few question on how best to represent a map in UML. But how do you show the following:

```
class KeyType
{
public:
    KeyType(const int someValue);

private:
    int m_someValue;
};

class SomeType
{
private:
    std::map<KeyType,float> m_mapAttr;
};
```

Where the map key is a class and the associated values are plain types. I would like to know how to represent both the attribute and the relationship between the classes.

Comment: Which language? Map is some associative array?

Comment: Yeah @qwerty_so, it's an associative array. Language is C++ but that should be irrelevent to how to show it in UML

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226340/3379653

Comment: @qwerty_so sorry, this was an automatic comment from SO when I entered a closed vote for duplicate with your link. I didn't type it myself ! I deleted to avoid confusion

Comment: @qwerty_so that link seems to be about UML diagrams where the map uses a simple data type for the key and associates to a class type. I want it the other way around.